# Generalized Least Square When Disturbance Covariance Matrix Is Rank Deficient

Tags: generalized-least-squares, blue, gauss-markov-theorem

I cannot find any general results on the following *Generalized Least Square (GLS)* problem.

Let $Y = X\beta + E$, where $X$ is deterministic and of full column rank $k$, and $E$ is of zero mean, with a $n$-by-$n$ covariance matrix $V$ with rank $r < n$. Let $V^+$ be the unique Moore-Penrose inverse of $V$.  It is further assumed that $X'V^+X$ is invertible.

**Question:** What is the best linear unbiased estimator (BLUE) of $\beta$?

You would think the answer must be $(X'V^+X)^{-1}X'V^+Y$.  But that  would be actually wrong.

*N.B. :* This has nothing to do with multicollinearity. This problem arises when we have "redundant" observations and/or infinitely precise observations. For the former, we generally drop the redundant observations.  For the latter, which are basically linear restrictions of the parameters, we generally re-parameterize to incorporate such restrictions directly.  I would like to find a unified approach. My guess is $(X'V^+X)^{-1}X'V^+Y$ works for the former case only.

Comment: Hint: a suitable linear combination of the observations will have uncorrelated errors.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, whuber.  But I think you are suggesting the following, find a $r$-by-$n$ matrix, $\Gamma$, such that we have $\Gamma Y = \Gamma X \beta + \Gamma E$ with $\Gamma V \Gamma'$ being full rank and diag.  This still addresses my case 1 only (i.e. redundant obs).  Consider the special case of 2 observations, where the matrix $V$ has 0 everywhere except it has 1 at the (1,1) element.  This is already diag, should we choose $\Gamma$ as (1, 0) to simply drop the second observation?  The answer actually depends on whether $X$ variable is zero or not.